# Python NetworkX finding an specific subgraph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, complex-networks

Assume that we turned a UML diagram into a directed graph with labeled edges (edges has labels like "Association" or "Generalization"). Is there any way to find a specific subgraph, say finding the graph of the Factory design pattern in this graph using NetworkX APIs?

Comment: Could you provide an example for your input and expected output?

Comment: @abc Input if graph G1, which is any directed graph where nodes are C++ classes and edges are either Association or Generalization, and also a graph G2 which is for example the graph representation of the [Strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy) *There is an image in the link with title Route planning strategies*. Output is all the subgraph where their relations are the same as G2.

Comment: For example assume G1={(c, d), (a, b), (b, c), (a, c), (b, e)} and G2 = {(m, n), (m, o), (n, o)} the output is [{(a, b), (b, c), (a, c)}]